# OpenCV: Take a picture when face, eyes and smile detected

Tags: opencv, face-detection

**Hello!**

I am trying to write a model with OpenCV to detect the face, open eyes, and smile, and once detected automatically take and save a snapshot.

I am using this code, which does detection, but takes a snapshot when a key (in my case "q") is pressed. But I want to achieve an automatic break of the control when all the features (face, eyes, smile) are detected at the moment.

**I would appreciate any advice :)**

```
def detect(gray, frame):
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.5, 7)
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), ((x + w), (y + h)), (255, 0, 0), 2)
        reg_gray = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        reg_color = frame[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        smiles = smile_cascade.detectMultiScale(reg_gray, 1.8, 20)
        for (sx, sy, sw, sh) in smiles:
            cv2.rectangle(reg_color, (sx, sy), ((sx + sw), (sy + sh)), (0, 0, 255), 2)
    for (p, q, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (p, q), ((p + w), (q + h)), (255, 0, 0), 2)
        reg_gray = gray[q:q + h, p:p + w]
        reg_color = frame[q:q + h, p:p + w]
        eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(reg_gray, 1.8, 20)
        for (sp, sq, sw, sh) in eyes:
            cv2.rectangle(reg_color, (sp, sq), ((sp + sw), (sq + sh)), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    return frame

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0) 

while True: 

    _, frame = video_capture.read() 

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 

    canvas = detect(gray, frame) 

    cv2.imshow('Video', canvas) 

    # The control breaks once q is pressed                       
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff == ord('q'):            
        break


video_capture.release()
```

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
if len(smiles) > 0 and len(eyes) > 0:
     cv2.imwrite("smile_and_eyes.jpg", canvas)
```

should do.